# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V Exception while migrating from 12.1.3 to 12.2

Tags: weblogic12c, hibernate-5.x

I am doing migration from JDev 12.1.3 to 12.2.0. Now there was some problem durnng compilation but it has been resolved by modifiying class path.
Now when I go for deployment then it showing me one exception. That is ...

"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V"

I am using following dependencies..

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Apart from these dependencies I also looked into "C:\oracle_home12c\wlserver\modules" folder and found there was one "org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging.jar" file.
I replaced the maven repo file from "jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final".
I also looked into "jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final" jar file. There is one Logger class file but it does not contain the debugf(String) method.

Exception type;

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    at org.hibernate.internal.NamedQueryRepository.checkNamedQueries(NamedQueryRepository.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(SessionFactoryImpl.java:764)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:495)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:802)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:135)
    at weblogic.persistence.BasePersistenceUnitInfo.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfo.java:611)
```

Can someone help to get rid off this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the glassfish server the the problem might be with the lib provided by glassfish. This error is caused by the use of incompatible version.

Just create a `glassfish-web.xml` file in the `WEB-INF` directory. The contents of the file are shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
     <class-loader delegate="false"/>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

This ensures that glassfish does not load it's internal libraries, but libraries from your project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how JDev classloading works, but maybe it takes the a wrong version of jboss-logging which doesn't have the method? Try removing that from the modules dir. And make sure that your app bundles jboss-logging in the .war. It should  be brought in by Hibernate's dependencies. If not, add it to the pom.xml.